# How to disable current logger with same fileHandler?

Tags: python-3.x, logging

I have two different classes in which I use this logging function

utils.py file -

```
import logging 
import os    

def get_logger(LOG_DIR, LOG_FILE):
    
"""Create logger."""

    # Create LOG_DIR if it doesn't exist already
    if not os.path.exists(LOG_DIR):
        os.makedirs(f"{LOG_DIR}")

    try:
        # Create logger and set level
        logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        logger.setLevel(level=logging.INFO)

        # Configure file handler
        formatter = logging.Formatter(
            fmt = '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
            datefmt = "%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S"
            )
        fh = logging.FileHandler(f"{os.path.join(LOG_DIR,LOG_FILE)}")
        fh.setFormatter(formatter)
        fh.setLevel(level=logging.INFO)

        # Add handlers to logger
        logger.addHandler(fh)
        return  logger

    except Exception as e:
        print("Problem getting logger.")
        print(e)
```

Now for both the classes and the main function the format is something like:

class1.py file -

```
from utils import get_logger

def Class1():
    def __init__(self):
       self.logger = get_logger(dir_path, log_file1.log)
    def fn():
       self.logger.info('Hi. This resides in log_file1.log')
```

class2.py file -

```
from utils import get_logger

def Class2():
    def __init__(self):
       self.logger = get_logger(dir_path, log_file2.log)
    def fn():
       self.logger.info('Hi. This resides in log_file2.log')
```

main_fn.py file -

```
import class1
import class2

a = class1()
a.fn()

b = class2()
b.fn()
```

The way I intended the log files to be updated was,

```
log_file1.log:
utils-INFO-'Hi. This resides in log_file1.log'

log_file2.log:
utils-INFO-'Hi. This resides in log_file2.log'
```

But, what actually happened was,

```
log_file1.log:
utils-INFO-'Hi. This resides in log_file1.log'
utils-INFO-'Hi. This resides in log_file2.log'

log_file2.log:
utils-INFO-'Hi. This resides in log_file2.log'
```

Due to some reason, the log_file1.log is getting updated for the Class2 functions as well. Can anyone suggest in what way can I get the intended result?

Would setting "logging.config.fileConfig('filename.log', disable_existing_loggers=False)" solve my problem?

Comment: `logger.addHandler(fh)` Does this sound any bells ? Basically,  you are appending new log endpoints to an existing logger. So, it gets published every where.

Comment: So in order to get the kind of logs that I want, would I have to create new log instances(get_logger) in my classes? Or what should I do? I'm sorry I'm very new to this topic.